# SSLHandshakeException Trust anchor for certification path not found Android HTTPS

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, openssl

I'm trying to establish a connection to a HTTPS site and I got this exception: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`.
My original code is as follows:

```
URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            byte[] responsedata = CommonUtil.readInputStream(in);
            Log.w(TAG, "response is "+CommonUtil.convertBytesToHexString(responsedata));
```

Then, I read Google's article [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) and modified my code to:

```
CertificateFactory cf;
        try {
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream in = this.mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
            Certificate ca;
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(in);
                System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
                in.close();
                URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
                HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                byte[] responsedata = CommonUtil.readInputStream(in);
            Log.w(TAG, "response is "+CommonUtil.convertBytesToHexString(responsedata));
            in.close();
```

Regarding the `R.raw.cert` file, I use [this site](https://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/) to check the certificates of the site. I found 3 cetificates and I have no idea which one to use. I tried them one by one.
The one name "VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5" results in the following exceptions:

```
01-17 17:46:54.759: E/Process(8764): java.security.cert.CertificateException: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

When I use the one named "VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3" or the one with the name "example.com" (same as the site name) I got the same `SSLHandshakeException`.

What do I need to do?

At the same time, [Symatec SSL Toolbox](https://ssltools.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp) shows me an error and 1 recommendation which I don't understand:

```
Intermediate certificate missing.
VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3

Update your certificate chain.
Your certificate chain is valid, but some older browsers may not recognize it. To support older browsers, download and install the missing intermediate certificate
```

The 3 certificates found for the site are as follows:
**example.com**:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5**:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: you need to update the certificate file if you have added in your project.

Comment: fuzzybee - "... and I got this exception." - what exception?

Comment: fuzzybee - "...  I found 3 and I have no idea which one to use" - used for what? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: fuzzybee - "...PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line..." - this tells you there is no `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` or its there but lacks a linefeed ("\n" in Java and C/C++). Be sure the certificate in PEM format.

Comment: fuzzybee - " Symatec SSL Toolbox shows me an error... " - what site are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Hi @noloader, how to check whether it's PEM or not PEM?

Comment: fuzzybee - `cat` it and look for `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` (and friends). If you hard coded them into your program, be sure to include the newline `"\n"` for each line.

Comment: Thanks @noloader, they all have that as mentioned in my updates above

Comment: If the CA is not trusted (or, the particular root is not trusted even though the CA is trusted), then use a custom `TrustManager` and override `checkServerTrusted`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742028/overriding-the-ssl-trust-manager-in-android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updates:**

- I've never been an expert at this matter, the following is only a workaround and might not be secure, use it at your own risk
- This post is 3+ years old, so it may be outdated by now (code will not compile) but you should find be able to find the updated approach or official docs saying certain parts are deprecated or removed

Thank noloader for pointing me in the correction direction. I solved my issue using the following:

```
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);// my question shows how to get 'ca'
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
    TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
// Initialise the TMF as you normally would, for example:
tmf.init(ca); 

TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
final X509TrustManager origTrustmanager = (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0];

TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
   new X509TrustManager() {
       public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
          return origTrustmanager.getAcceptedIssuers();
       }

       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           origTrustmanager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
       }

       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           try {
               origTrustmanager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
           } catch (CertificateExpiredException e) {
               // Do what you need to do, log to Crashlytics?
           }
       }
   }
};

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Out of the 3 certificates found for the site, mentioned in my question, the one that worked for me was the **VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3**

Comment: You did this on the client-side, or server-side?

Comment: this was done on client side, Android code @IgorGanapolsky

Comment: I'm getting this `java.io.IOException: Hostname someHostName was not verified` any idea?

Comment: This is not even a solution. If you get a `CertificateExpiredException` it will be silent and it will connect to the server anyways. This makes an attack by man in the middle possible.

Comment: `tmf.init(ca);` you cannot initialize a TrustManagerFactory with a Certificate, this code doesn't even compile, and if it would it makes SSL pointlessly insecure like @luiscosta noted.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was running my server on Https on local host i have to switch to http and it worked maybe the ssl certificate of the server is not trusted by the android device