# Error in android application with SSLHandshakeException, Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, sslhandshakeexception, javax

I am trying to make an android application,
 but on submitting the data it shows the error 
as follow:

```
 Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
 Trust anchor for certification path not found
```

Comment: This happens when you're trying to call an API which has unsigned SSL certificate.

Comment: Then how to sign or use this SSL certificate

Comment: check with your server side team and ask them. Other wise you could trust all certificates from your android app for now (kind of a workaround, not a fix).There are tutorials out there. But make sure not to use the same in production.

Comment: I am absolutely new to android development and don't know about this certificates , Can you suggest me few methods to overcome this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSLHandshakeException Trust anchor for certification path not found Android HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183043/sslhandshakeexception-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-android-http)