# Android : Programmatically trust Certificate Authority

Tags: android, certificate, ca

I am enrolling my email against an exchange server authenticated by CA cert. How do I make my device trust the CA programmatically so that it an be authenticated using the CA cert ?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. You can refer to this link on this site for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device I have used **alexander.egger** answer which perfectly work for the same kind of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the whole device trust a certificate from your program without root, only the user can add certificates in settings. But you can make your program trust any certificate. For that, see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742028/overriding-the-ssl-trust-manager-in-android).

Comment: @StenSoft I just want my app to trust my Certificate Authority not the whole device.

Comment: See the link in my answer for how to do that