# Can an expired certificate generate a sun.security.validator.ValidatorException error?

Tags: java, ssl, securityexception, self-signed-certificate

I'm currently representing a colleague on vacation. One of the applications he was in charge of has been reporting the following error for a few days.

> Error: IOException sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I did some research and found out that it might be related to a self-signed certificate which is not found in the trust store.

But since I haven't changed anything and everything worked fine before, can it be that the certificate has expired? Can an expired certificate produce such an error message? If so, can I somehow determine the expiration date from a key store file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like an expired certificate. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670503/java-ssl-tls-ignore-expired-cert-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception) the expired certificate should produced `CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed` message e.g.

```
qtp1735121130-17, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed:
   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
```

You can take a look at [How to Analyze Java SSL Errors](https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors) article to see what else can you do, it boils down to using `-Djava.net.debug` option and analyzing logs.

I'd start by comparing the self-signed certification in trust store against the one that is actually used on the environment. Self-signed certificates are easy to issue, perhaps someone has issued a new version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the recommended links. Since the info "timestamp check failed" is missing, it will not be the expiration date i think. I will investigate it further and in case of success post the solution. It will probably take a while because I'm neither so experienced in java nor in security issues.